Whenever I try to register a user mongoDb database, it throws an error : Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()
I am using Prisma Adapter with Next auth and google provider Whenever I try to register a new user in my database it throws an error :
Unknown argument provider_providerAccountId. Did you mean providerId_providerAccountId? Available options are marked with ?. PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid prisma.account.findUnique() invocation:
Here is my code
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from "../../../../lib/prisma";

export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  jwt: {
    async encode({ secret, token }) {
      return jwt.sign(token, secret);
    },
    async decode({ secret, token }) {
      return jwt.verify(token, secret);
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


Here is my schema
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

// Looking for ways to speed up your queries, or scale easily with your serverless or edge functions?
// Try Prisma Accelerate: https://pris.ly/cli/accelerate-init

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
model Account {
  id                 String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  providerType       String
  providerId         String
  providerAccountId  String
  refreshToken       String?
  accessToken        String?
  accessTokenExpires DateTime?
  createdAt          DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime  @updatedAt
  userId             String     @db.ObjectId
  user               User       @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id]) // Corrected relation with User

  @@unique([providerId, providerAccountId])
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt

  accounts      Account[] // Inverse relation with Account
}

model Subreddit {
  id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name        String   @unique
  description String
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Posts {
  id          String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title       String
  description String
  type        String
  userId      String     @db.ObjectId // Reference to User
  subredditId String     @db.ObjectId // Reference to Subreddit
  createdAt   DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime   @updatedAt
  votes       Int        @default(0) 
}

model Comment {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  postId    String   @db.ObjectId // Reference to Post
  userId    String   @db.ObjectId // Reference to User
  content   String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now()) 
}


I tried different solution, added unique filed and tried using callbacks. nothing helped.

Your version is old. It should be provider_providerAccountId 
Last actual document: 
https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/prisma
Update prisma schema and run the migration:
$ npx prisma generate
$ npx prisma migrate dev

